# How to keep the squares from expanding

Tags: html, css

I have this square 3x3 grid that I want to create the game of tic-tac-toe with, but when I put an X or O in one of the divs, it causes the cell to expand. I want to find a solution so that each cell maintains its square shape.

```css
.grid {
  display: table;
  border-spacing: 5px;
  background: black;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  max-height: 80px;
  max-width: 80px;
  background: white;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell" id="1"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="2">X</div>
    <div class="cell" id="3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell" id="4"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="5"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="6"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell" id="7"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="8"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="9"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you might want to use `position: absolute`

Comment: I tried using this before asking this question, but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe you forget to add `position: relative` to its parent.

Comment: "How to keep the squares from expanding" is not the title I gave to my question. This new title invented by an SO moderator is much more vague and difficult to find in search results. I would not be able to find the answer I was looking for with this title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be achievable using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex).

```css
.grid {
  display: table;
  background: black;
  height: 240px;
  width: 240px;
  border: 2.5px solid black;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}
.cell {
  display: flex;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  max-height: 80px;
  max-width: 80px;
  background: white; 
  border: 2.5px solid black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
div {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell" id="1"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="2">X</div>
    <div class="cell" id="3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell" id="4"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="5"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="6">X</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell" id="7"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="8">O</div>
    <div class="cell" id="9"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using `display: table` is `display: grid`.

You can use `grid` to set up the layout, and `flexbox` to center the cell content.

To create the cell borders you can wrap the grid in a container with a background colour, then use `grid-gap` to "reveal" it.

```css
.container {
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 5px solid;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 80px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 80px);
  grid-gap: 5px;
}

.cell {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: white;
  /* center the cell content */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="grid">
    <div class="cell" id="1"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="2">X</div>
    <div class="cell" id="3"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="4"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="5"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="6"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="7"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="8"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="9"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work.

```
.grid {
  display: table;
  background: black;
  height: 240px;
  width: 240px;
  border: 2.5px solid black;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
}
.cell {
  display: flex;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  max-height: 80px;
  max-width: 80px;
  background: white; 
  border: 2.5px solid black;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
div {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;

}
```

And the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <div class="grid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell" id="1"><span class="sign">X</span></div>
    <div class="cell" id="2"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell" id="4"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="5"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="6"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell" id="7"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="8"></div>
    <div class="cell" id="9"></div>
  </div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added an X in one of the divs so that it is clear what the cell is doing.

Comment: If you run the code snippet from my question, you should see the top row with the x expanded into a rectangle.

Comment: What browser you use, maybe its related.

Comment: Browser: Firefox 58.0.2

Answer (score 0):

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 20px;
  background: black;
}

td {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  max-height: 80px;
  max-width: 80px;
  background: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table class='grid'>
  <tr>
    <td class='cell'>X</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

EDIT:

I think the use of `display:table`, `display:table-row`, `display:table-cell` causes the problem.

Comment: Edited the answer, it seem using vanilla `table`, `tr` and `td` tag will not cause this problem.